# How to return value from table's DataSource to main report in iReport?

Tags: return, jasper-reports, ireport

I have a table in my iReport which naturally has its dataset and I have a variable, that is defined and initialized in the table's dataset return a value (which definitely does within scope of table, not outside it) which I want to use in my main report which holds the table.

How can I do that or any alternatives?

Answer (score 12):

The correct way (jasper report v.5/v.6) to return values from a component using `subDataset` is to use variables, define variables in both main report and in `subDataset`.

**Example** (return record count of table to main report)

1. In main report define a variable

   ```xml
   <variable name="TABLE_COUNT" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="None">
      <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[0]]></initialValueExpression>
   </variable>
   ```
2. In `subdataset` define a variable (in example a build in variable will be used `$V{REPORT_COUNT}`).
3. In `datasetRun` indicate which `subDataset` variable (`fromVariable`)
   should be return to which main report variable (`toVariable`)

   ```xml
   <datasetRun subDataset="tableData" uuid="fa5df3de-f4c5-4bfc-8274-bd064e8b81e6">
      <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
      <returnValue fromVariable="REPORT_COUNT" toVariable="TABLE_COUNT"/>
   </datasetRun>
   ```

The `TABLE_COUNT` variable can then be used in the main report, just remember to set correct [evaluationTime](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/type/EvaluationTimeEnum.html)

**Display the value** (in main report)

```xml
<textField evaluationTime="Report">
    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="d67ddb3e-b0cc-4fae-9e05-f40eb0f7e059"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{TABLE_COUNT}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Comment: Very nice  answer :)

Comment: What is the evaluationTime link supposed to tell? 
Can you please add a working configuration. I can't get it to work and it would be nice if the example were complete and repeatable. Thank You!

Comment: @Soundbytes the evaluationTime link is there to explain how to get the textField to evalute at a desired time (a fundamental concept in jasper report), if you see the example on how to display the value it has `evaluationTime="Report"` which is fundamental to get the correct result. If you like to understand what that is follow the link.

Comment: @PetterFriberg I tried but always get null. What did I miss out? Should I define variable in the subdataset to the fields return from query?

Comment: @stuckedoverflow I need to see your example, maybe you forgot to set the evaulationTime on the text field?

Comment: @PetterFriberg thanks for replying. I almost give up but I realized that I can see the error details. (Sorry new to Jasper Reports). My case was the variable class of String cast to Double issue. Now it's ok thanks again.

Comment: @PetterFriberg It's oot but can we get dataset run return value to text field instead of using list? List I cannot format it for example to currency format.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to get some data from the table dataset, you actually can do this. I found a dirty trick to achieve this.

1. Create VARIABLE `variableMapName` of type `java.util.Map` in main report and initialize it with expression `new java.util.HashMap()`
2. Create PARAMETER `parameterMapName` of type `java.util.Map` within table dataset
3. Link dataset PARAMETER with variable from main report using **"Edit table datasource -> Parameters -> Add -> $P{parameterMapName} = $V{variableMapName}"** (right click on the table in main report template)
4. Create variable `putResult` of type `java.lang.String` in table datasource. Expression for this variable will looks like this

`$P{parameterMapName}.put("KEY", $F{fieldYouWantReturn}) + $P{parameterMapName}.put("KEY2", $F{otherFieldYouWantReturn})`

Now you have an ability to use the data from table datasource in main report by using `$V{variableMapName}.get("KEY")`

It is  really a dirty hack, but sometimes you have no other way to do something. 
Thanks!

Comment: Tried this solution and didn't work. Can't see how the putResult will send data after the table was generated to a print method that was done before table creation

Comment: Thank you my fried, I just have to use toString() im my sum of dataset to acess it in my report, in this way i can sum all my results from dataset, it is realy very usefull tip

Answer (score 1):

It sounds reasonable... but I'm not sure whether it's possible. It could be a useful enhancement request.

An alternative is to use a subreport. Anything possible in a Table is possible in a Subreport. Subreports have Return Values, and that will let you pass back the information you need.

Comment: Thank you mdahlman for the answer. As you quoted 'it could be a useful enhancement request' for iReport IDE development-team. And of course, a sub-report can return values to its main report; which is also one way.But I wished if there could be any way to return values from table to its Main-report ? please, if someone has any further idea on the stuff i asked for ?

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to return a variable from the dataset of a table to the main report , whereas the vice versa is possible. An Alternative can be as suggested by mdahlman. Use a Sub-Report instead.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can return value from from the dataset of a table to the main report.

On `jasper studio 6.0.1,I` found a property named dataset of table, it has return values set. But get into the set , I found the form "configure the return values" is wrong, jasper studio get wrong with "from variable to variable" , stuio reverse the two variable. "from variable" is table's local variable, "to value" is  main report variable.You must manaualedit in source , and remove `"incrementerFactoryClass=""".`

I test ,it is ok .The return value is printed on main report.

next is a piece of my jrxml.

```html
<jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
     <datasetRun subDataset="workscore" uuid="307278bc-db98-4de2-9b50-dea5dc69b496">
      <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
      <returnValue fromVariable="returnscore" toVariable="workscore"/>
     </datasetRun>
```

Answer (score 0):

For Map Type it is possible for rest any type returning value from table-set to the main report is not possible.

Although one can use sub-report as there is options for returning values.If possible try to use sub-reports in place of Table.