# Jaspersoft studio calculate variables before detail band

Tags: jasper-reports

Jaspersoft studio 6.2.

The report below, there are 3 bands: title, detail, and summary. Detail is in the middle. Look at "Activated staff" on the top on title band, it used a variable (activatedstaffcount1) as expression. The variable sum all activated staff counts in the detail. However it shows null. The bottom one is in the summary band and used the same variable but it shows correct number. The middle section is the data (detail band).  I want to show aggregated result before the display data(detail band), how can I do it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I show sum of columns in column header?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35264230/how-can-i-show-sum-of-columns-in-column-header)

Comment: I have purposed a duplicate where you can find an example that I did, check it out if it is what you need and let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set also Evaluation time in the text field which contains that variable to the "Report".

If the text field is outside of the table - try to [return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10394401/how-to-return-value-from-tables-datasource-to-main-report-in-ireport) into the parameter back from dataset and display that parameter at the end of report evaluation.

Comment: Try to set also Evaluation time in the text field which contains that variable to the "Report". - That works!